# Read and Edit Configuration Properties in Java Jersey Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I have a simple Java web service written using Maven-Jersey. It has two functions - getallusers and getuser

```
@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService
{
    UserDao userDao = new UserDao(DevMode.DEV_MODE);
    private static final String SUCCESS_RESULT = "{\"result\":\"success\"}";
    private static final String FAILURE_RESULT = "{\"result\":\"failure\"}";

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<User2> getUsers()
    {
       return userDao.getAllUsers();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/users/{userid}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User2 getUser(@PathParam("userid") int userid)
    {
       return userDao.getUser(userid);
   }
}
```

UserDao is reading from a user.json file. Now I want to set the DevMode.DEV_MODE in the configuration file. Something like `deployment_mode="Dev"` So that I can change it during deployment or when running unit tests. I am using the DevMode to read from different files like userdev.json or usertest.json.

Is there a way to read this configuration file when UserService is getting started? Or Is there a way I can modify those configuration parameters once UserService is up?

UPDATE: Still I don't know how to read or modify a configuration properties for a web service. As a work around, in the unit test I have added @Before and @After. In @Before function, I am manually moving the actually db file that is user.json to temp and creating a test user.json file. In @After function I am moving back the temp file to replace the test user.json. This is definitely a dirty way to fix this.

Comment: Using maven? Can you show userDao impl where it reads json?

Comment: @pirho Yes used Maven to setup. Here is the link for userDao file - [UserDao.java](https://github.com/harsha-kadekar/WebServiceTutorial/blob/master/restwebappexample/src/main/java/org/shiksha/webapp/UserDao.java)

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?